# Не получается сравнить счета игроков в игре Угадай число

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Недавно начала изучать JS. Никак не могу разобраться как сравнить счета игроков по количеству ходов. Заранее извиняюсь если что то неразумное вышло, я новичок.
В главном меню если выбрать игру в раунд, пользователь и компьютер играют по очереди. По количество шагов  в каждом раунде даются очки. Количество шагов считаются в функции и для пользователя и для компьютера. А вытащить данные не получается

```js
let count = 1;

let getRandomInt = (max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max) + 1);
};

let makeCounter = () => {
  let currentCount = 1;
  return {
    getNext: function() {
      return currentCount++;
    },
    reset: function() {
      currentCount = 1;
    }
  };
}
let counter = makeCounter();


let playGameForUser = () => {
  randomInt = getRandomInt(100);
  console.log(randomInt); // console
  while (count > 0) {
    let user = prompt('Guess the number. User says:');
    if (user === null) {
      break;
    } else if (isNaN(+user) || user === '') {
      alert('Please enter only numbers')
    } else if (+user < randomInt) {
      alert('greater');
    } else if (+user > randomInt) {
      alert('less')
    } else if (+user === randomInt) {
      alert(`Yes? It is!
Got it in ${counter.getNext()} steps!`);
      break;
    }
    counter.getNext();
  }
  counter.reset();
};

let playGameForComputer = () => {
  while (count > 0) {
    let randomInt = getRandomInt(100);
    let computer = prompt(`Computer asks:
is it ${randomInt} ?
(Enter less, greater or yes)`);
    if (computer === null) {
      break;
    } else {
      computer = computer.toLowerCase();
      if (computer === 'less' || computer === 'greater') {

      } else if (computer === 'yes') {
        alert(`Got it in ${counter.getNext()} steps!`);
        break;
      } else {
        alert('Please enter right answer')
      }
    }
    counter.getNext();
  }
  counter.reset();
};

let playWithTurn = () => {
  let turn = prompt('Enter the number of rounds');
  if (turn === '') {
    turn = 3;
  } else {
    turn = +turn;
  };
  while (count < (+turn + 1)) {
    let scoreForUser = 0;
    let scoreForComputer = 0;
    alert(`Round ${count} `);
    playGameForUser();
    playGameForComputer();
    switch (true) {
      case (counter.getNext < counter.getNext):
        scoreForUser++; break;
      case (counter.getNext > counter.getNext):
        scoreForComputer++; break;
      case (counter.getNext === counter.getNext):
        scoreForComputer++ && scoreForUser++; break;
    }

    alert(`Score:
user ${scoreForUser}
computer: ${scoreForComputer}`)
    count++
  }
};

let chooseModeTheGame = () => {
  while (count > 0) {
    let mode = prompt(`Choose the mode of game (user or computer or round):
                                
user - You need guess the number;
computer - Computer try to guess the number
round - You take turns playing with the computer `);
    if (mode === null) {
      alert('Bye. See you later');
      break;
    } else {
      mode = mode.toLowerCase();
      if (mode === 'user') {
        playGameForUser();
      } else if (mode === 'computer') {
        playGameForComputer();
      } else if (mode === 'round') {
        playWithTurn()
      }
    }
  };
};

chooseModeTheGame()
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на СО.  Пожалуйста, отформатируйте ваш код и уменьшите его до [минимального примера, воспроизводящего проблему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Если что то уменьшить код работать совсем не будет. Может комментарии добавить где не получается?

Comment: У вас, кстати, в `switch` `break` не забыты?

Comment: c break или без работают одинаково

Answer (score 0):

- Вам надо, чтобы `playGameForUser` и `playGameForComputer` в конце
  выполнения(раунда) возвращали итоговое количество затраченных ходов.
- В свою очередь `playWithTurn` должен принимать и обрабатывать
  возвращаемое значение функций `playGameFor...`.
- Количество ходов для функций лучше считать через локальные
  переменные в функциях `playGameFor...`, а не через `makeCounter`

Схематичный пример логики.

`

```js
let playGameForUser = () => {
  let counter // вместо makeCounter локальная переменная, для хранения количества ходов
  //код игры
  return counter //возвращаем итоговое количество ходов
}

let playGameForComputer => {
  let counter // // вместо makeCounter локальная переменная, для хранения количества ходов
  //код игры
  return counter //возвращаем итоговое количество ходов
}


let playWithTurn => {
    //Стартовый счет. 
    let score = {
      user: 0;
      computer: 0
    }

    /* ваш код игры */

    //цикл игры
    //playGameForUser() и ForComputer() возвращают количество ходов, в текущем примере 1 ход = 1 очку, вы делайте, как вам нужно.
    while (true) {
      score.user += playGameForUser();
      score.computer += playGameForComputer();
    }

    //после выполнения цикла, вы можете работать с итоговым значением score
    let winner = //какие-то операции со score
      console.log(`Winner is ${winner})
  }
```